# Parse Server resource limits

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

I am looking into migrating my parse.com app to parse server with either AWS or Heroku.

The primary frustration I encountered with Parse in the past has been the resource limits

https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-resource-limits

Am I correct in assuming that following a migration the resource limits will be dependant on the new host (i.e. AWS or Heroku)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Parse Server is simply a nodejs module which means that wherever you choose to host your nodejs app will decide which resource limits that will be imposed. You might also be able to set them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I recently moved it to AWS , so yes as stated in a comment its just a nodejs module so you have complete control over it. So mainly constraints here will be cpu , i/o and network of AWS. I would suggest reading the documentation provided here https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server , they have also mentioned which ec2 instances we should take so that we can scale  node and mongo properly.